# MySQL Insert operation are slow on Linux RDS server

Tags: linux, insert, innodb, performance-testing, mysql-5.7

[please check the workbench output after 20 mints its writing only 100-200 records persecond before that its writing 1211-2000 writes per second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIqOL.png) I am trying to insert 2 million records on the MySQL 5.7.10 RDS server, Its taking almost 40 mints to insert the data on Linux environment  where as the same data are inserted in 28 mints on Windows platform.

On Linux I am using SSD disk still its taking long time to insert.

**My hardware configuration is:**-

SSD Disk

RAM:- 122 GB

CPU:- 16 Cores

**My MySQL configuration is:-**

innodb_buffer_pool_size=80 G

innodb_log_file_size= 1G

innodb_log_buffer_size= 64MB

innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 28

tmp_table_size =4G

max_heap_size= 4G

table_open_cache=32262

innodb_file_per_table=ON

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2

innodb_flush_method=O-DIRECT

Team please check and help on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Same HW for both machines? Did you do any system monitoring on both cases?

Comment: @FDavidov thanks for prompt response. hardware configuration is different on windows i have 28 cores CPU and 128 GB of RAM

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp_table_size =4G  -- lower to 1G
max_heap_size= 4G   -- lower to 1G
table_open_cache=32262  -- lower to, say, 1000
```

What filesystem (xfs, ext4, etc)?  RAID?

Please show us the insert command(s).  Where is the source data coming from (same drive, different machine, etc)?

**More**

Batch the `INSERTs` -- but `BEGIN` and `COMMIT` around 100-1000 rows at a time.

Comment: thanks, this is the query which i found in my innodb status;   "INSERT INTO OTALineups_new1(PostalCode, ProgSvcId, LCN, LineupType, Country)
       VALUES(Postal_Code, ProgramSVCID, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(chanList, CONCAT('$[', chan ,']'))), LineupType, CountryCode);"

Comment: (I augmented my answer.)

Answer (score 0):

There is a single line setting that can resolve the issue:

innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

Comment: I already set it to innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2

still its taking 40 mints